# How aMuseing, this guy!

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Ah- there you are! Care to help me out? Creativity is good, but it's got me stumped this time around. Ronald invited me to an evening party of his for halloween. Everyone was supposed to dress up and think up of an interesting name. That's all fine and dandy, but this ninja came up with a riddle to make us figure out his name! I'm terrible at riddles, if you could even consider this one. Once he got our attentions by slamming the table, he began to speak. Not that you have to help, but can you figure it out?

> "I am here, yet you cannot see me. But... I suppose if you give me food I'll show up. I exist- but do I really? If you can't see me, how can you prove it? I'll tell you how- nothing escapes once I set my eyes on it; and if I make it disappear, then I must surely be real! I am the child of death; the Force is with me. Anything in my path shall move or face my wrath. With my powerful rays- POW POW!- and my ability to stop time, I'll determine who lives and who dies. Now, my precious party-goers, who am I?"

The ninja stands on the table and strikes a terribly embarrassing pose, awaiting our answer. He begins to cycle through different poses, as if he'd been practicing them beforehand for this moment of fame. I've got to think of something fast, if only to get him down from there!

Comment: Oh, how I dearly want the answer to be r13(wbua pran).....

Comment: I snorted when I decoded that-

Comment: Almost like you...didn't see him coming! ;P

Comment: Not that it's important, but... [how aMuseing.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OgvLej8ln2w)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's

> **a black hole**

**Explanation:**

I am here, yet you cannot see me.

> That's why they are called black holes

But... I suppose if you give me food I'll show up.

> Black holes require the fuel of an exploding star.

I exist- but do I really? If you can't see me, how can you prove it?

> This is a reference to how difficult it was to explain the phenomenon black holes caused.

I'll tell you how- nothing escapes once I set my eyes on it; and if I make it disappear, then I must surely be real!

> Reference to a black hole's intense gravity.

I am the child of death; the Force is with me.

> It is caused by a dying star and keeps the gravity of said star.

Anything in my path shall move or face my wrath.

> When in a black's holes sphere of influence, other celestial bodies will either be flung away or drawn in by the black hole's gravity.

With my powerful rays- POW POW!-

> A reference to Hawking Radiation and his talk that ultimately gave him the credibility to be believed

and my ability to stop time,

> According to relativity, things at the centre of the black hole don't experience the passing of time

I'll determine who lives and who dies. Now, my precious party-goers, who am I?"

> a black hole

Comment: You're definitely right that it's a science-y answer! This ninja *truly* makes things disappear. "nothing escapes once I set my eyes on it" is quite a literal line, too :^)

Comment: I tried again, and now?

Comment: That would be it! An answer consists of two parts, though- the actual answer and the explanation; check mark's yours if you can take the riddle and show why the answer is what it is!

Comment: I attempted it, though it's difficult to format

Comment: Thank you, it's perfect :) The imaginary points go to you!